# Opening web page in editmode

Tags: javascript, html

I want to know how we can open a web page in edit mode within an HTML page.
I mean, suppose if I have two frames. when I enter a url in a text in top frame, I should get the page in edit mode in bottom page. I should be able to select the items in the page in that mode. I don't want to save the items, but should be able to switch to the normal mode in a button click.

This is for getting Id/name/xpath of the elements in that page. if there are controls in a page which will navigate to other pages while clicking, I wouldn't be able to detect these parameters. If I am overriding all the click events, the controls under javascript tabs/accradian, will not be accessible.

Is there any ways to do it?

I coded as per one of the answer, but it is not working.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>click demo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunc() {
           doc = ifrm.contentDocument || ifrm.contentWindow.document;
           doc.designMode = "on";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="text" value="http://www.google.com" />
    <input type="button" onclick="myFunc()" value="Open" /><br /><br />
    <iframe id="ifrm" src="http://www.example.com"  width="100%" height="500px" ></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What about using Firebug/Developer tools of the browser? You can choose any element and ask for the xpath/Css path to it

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I want to do it using javascript, I have to do it programatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can convert any frame to design mode

```
iframe_node.contentDocument.designMode = "on";
```

Comment: is is a cross platform and programmable solution?